# How to prove that this sequence converges to 1?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I have a sequence $p$ which is defined as:

$$p_{n+1} = \frac{rp_n}{rp_n + (1 - p_n)}$$

where $0 < p_0 \le 1$ and $r > 1$.

I want to show that this sequence converges to $1$, i.e. that:

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} p_n = 1$$

The sequence grows monotonically as $n$ gets bigger, if $r > 1$ and $0 < p_n < 1$ because:

$$\Delta p = p_{n+1} - p_n = \frac{rp_n}{rp_n + (1 - p_n)} - p_n = \big(\frac{r}{r - 1 + 1/p_n} - 1\big)p_n > 0$$

However, I have trouble showing that it converges to $1$. It does seem to be the case though. In the below figure, I have plotted $p$ for various values of $p0$,  $r$, and $\epsilon$, and $p$ always converges.

[image: convergence of p for various values]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, for a recurrence that you can prove has a limit you can just substitute the limit into the recurrence.  In your case the sequence is bounded above by $1$ and growing monotonically, so there is a limit which we will call $L$.  Then $$L=\frac {rL}{rL+1-L}\\(r-1)L^2=(r-1)L\\L=1$$
The growing monotonically depends on $r \gt 1$ which is given.

Another approach is to show the distance of the $p$s from $1$ decreases to zero.
$$p_{n+1} = \frac{rp_n}{rp_n + (1 - p_n)}\\
=1-\frac {1-p_n}{rp_n+(1-p_n)}\\1-p_{n+1}=(1-p_n)\frac 1{rp_n+(1-p_n)}$$
so the error is reduced by a factor greater than $1$

Comment: Would you happen to know any cases where one can no substitute the limit into the recurrence?

Comment: The prime example is where the limit does not exist.  For example, $a_1=2, a_{n+1}=a_n^2$  If we blindly sub in $L$ we get $L=L^2$ with solutions $0,1$.  Neither is the limit.  There are cases where we get more than one $L$ and have to choose the correct one.  Usually our proof that the limit exists shows which is the one we want.

Comment: Here's an explanation of why the first approach works: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LlfAEFD12QM

Answer (score 0):

$$
p_{k+1} = \frac{rp_k}{rp_k +(1-p_n)} = \frac{r}{(r-1) + \frac{1}{p_k}}
$$
or
$$
\frac{1}{p_{k+1}} = \frac{(r-1) + \frac{1}{p_k}}{r} = 1-\frac{1}{r} +\frac{1}{r}\frac{1}{p_k}
$$
or
$$
u_{k+1} =\alpha + \beta u_k
$$
Try to resolve this. Assuming that $p_k\neq 0$